# How to share parent HTML between two child Angular2 components?

Tags: angular, typescript, nested, components

I am pretty new to Angular in general. My application has multiple "pages (components)" that all share things in common -- header, general layout of the page, etc. They could be sharing css and html (instead of it being repeated in each component), but I'm not sure how to go about doing it. Here is essentially what I want to do:

```
<parentPage>
  <childPage1></childPage1>
</parentPage>

<parentPage>
  <otherChildPage></otherChildPage>
</parentPage>
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction? The "childPage1" and "otherChildPage" components are completely different. One has a bunch of links, the other a wall of formatted text with some images. But the overall layout of the page outside of those components is exactly the same between the two.

Comment: I guess I could have one stylesheet that its imported into each of the components. But that doesn't solve the shared html problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular is a "**Single** Page Application" framework. 
For example you if you had a login page your code might look something like this:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <header-component/>
    <login-component/>
  </body>
</html>
```

then when the user logs in angular removes the `login-component` and replaces it with a `profile-component`

```
<html>
  <body>
    <header-component/>
    <profile-component/>
  </body>
</html>
```

This way you only ever have 1 page and you can swap out components as required. I'd recommend following an angular(2?) tutorial which will explain how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

What you expect is basically a SPA website. if your application is going to have common UI lookup, 
sol 1: have your master piece of lookup at the root index.html and root component and child component follow up
sol 2: have your common sharing html as parent component, and then your child as 2 small components. so total you have 3 component.
sol 3: this approach can be easily achieved easily through UI-Routing - read and understand from google.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this structure will make sense

```
<parentPage>
  <container>
      <childPage1></childPage1>
      <otherChildPage></otherChildPage>
  </container>
</parentPage>
```

parentPage - could have your common layout

container - could have your child components where you could pick the correct child component (This is done in the container component's respective html file where you could use *ngIf to pick which child component you want to render)